# Planning to test our web application in Safari/Windows 7 instead of Safari/OS X & iOS

Tags: macos, ios, safari, windows, web-app

We got a recommendation to test our web application in Safari for OS X and iOS (iPad). Instead of using a MacBook/iPad will it be the correct way to confirm the compatibility of Safari OS X and iOS if I install Safari in Windows 7 and do testing?

Or do I really have to use OS X/iOS only instead of Windows 7 to confirm Safari compatibility?

Comment: IOS and OSX Safari differ so I expect Safari for Windows to differ - you need to test on the exact platform your user uses

Answer (score 2):

Safari for Windows was dropped at version 6, in 2012. It is no longer available for download, directly from Apple, though can be found on several file hosters.
The last version of Safari for Windows was 5.1.7, released May 9, 2012.

I would say testing against such an outdated version would not really be useful at all.

There's a long article on resurrecting it for Windows 10 [here](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/back-from-the-dead-using-apples-abandoned-safari-for-windows-today) though it doesn't deal with the comparison in security or real compatibility terms.